# Why is if (typeCar != 'X' || 'S' ||'L') is evaluating to always true

Tags: c++

```
cout << "Enter 'X' for uberX or 'S' for SUV or 'L' for luxury: "<< endl;
cin >> typeCar;
typeCar = toupper(typeCar);  
if (typeCar != 'X' || 'S' ||'L') 
{
    cout << "Enter X, S, or L"<<endl;
    system("pause"); 
}
```

Regardless of if I input 'X' 'S' or 'L', it always executes this statement. Same goes for when I put in lowercase.

Comment: if (typeCar != 'X' || typeCar != 'S' || typeCar != 'L')

Comment: use if (typeCar != 'X' || typeCar != 'S' || typeCar != 'L')

Comment: You both get an F :)

Comment: `if (typeCar != 'X' || 'S' ||'L')` should be `if ((typeCar != 'X') &&  (typeCar != 'S') && (typeCar != 'L'))` if I understood correctly what you want to do.

Answer (score -2):

You need to evaluate each statement separately.

```
if(typechar! = 'x' || typechar! = 'Z')
```

Comment: if and not If also this answer is already written.

Comment: This is the auto correct in my phone...